# Some Nircmd command not working on task scheduler

Tags: cmd, nircmd

i currently try to make script that prevent user to mute volume using nircmd .
but the script is fine when i run manually but when i run using task scheduler but only 2 line of system sound script executed, i try to make 2 different script between system sound and application sound result still same only system sound script executed.

```
nircmd.exe setsysvolume 13104 -->Working on task scheduler and can manually run 
nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 0-->Working on task scheduler and can manually run 

nircmd.exe muteappvolume mstsc.exe 0 -->Not working on task scheduler and can manually run 
nircmd.exe setappvolume mstsc.exe 13104 -->Not working on task scheduler and can manually run
```

Comment: On  http://www.nirsoft.net/contact-new.html there is a message " 
Contact NirSoft
If you have any problem, suggestion, comment, or you found a bug in NirSoft utility, you can send a message to nirsofer@yahoo.com". Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply .Ya i tried email them no reply ,Hi Moderator pls close this post .